# react native firebase how to trigger authstatechanged on other devices when profile updates

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobx-react, react-native-firebase

I am trying to figure out how I can trigger authstatechanged when the user updates their displayName or email on other devices.

I tried the experimental onUserChanged but that only works on the same device the user made the change. Right now the user would have to log off and log back on to see the changes on other devices.

How do I trigger the update on the other devices as soon as an update has been made?

Comment: This isn't something you can do with Auth alone - I'd recommend syncing user information using Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore and adding a real time listener to the location - that way changes can be listened to on any device.

Comment: Thank you I figured the built-in auth wasn't good enough and started using firestore. Your comment confirms that's the best method to deal with profiles.